# Reflection: method with generic argument and lambda expression as parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection, lambda

I really can't figure this one out...

I'm trying to achieve the following result using reflection:

```
_builder.Entity<Post>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
```

Let me introduce the variables... `_builder` is of type `DbModelBuilder` and `Post` has a property `Id` of type `Guid`.

In the code below, `contentType` wraps a `System.Type` :

```
var config = _builder.GetType()
    .GetMethod("Entity")
    .MakeGenericMethod(contentType.Type)
    .Invoke(_builder, null);

var hasKey = config.GetType().GetMethod("HasKey");

var expressionKey = typeof(Expression<>)
    .MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>)
    .MakeGenericType(contentType.Type, typeof(Guid)));

var paramEx = Expression.Parameter(contentType.Type, "t");
var lambdaEx = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(paramEx, "Id"), paramEx);

hasKey.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Guid))
    .Invoke(_builder, new[] { lambdaEx });
```

`HasKey` definition might help:

```
public EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> HasKey<TKey>(Expression<Func<TEntityType, TKey>> keyExpression);
```

... where `TEntityType` should be of type `Post` and `TKey` of type `Guid` ...

Exception of type `TargetException` is thrown (on the last call to Invoke above) :

> Object does not match target type.

I have tried every idea I could come up with and still I can't match the target type.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not to be blond here, but shouldnt your last invoke's instance parameter be config rather than _builder? :)

Comment: Just curious since i find the idea intriguing. Are you trying to to create some kind of dynamic EF ModelBuilder?

Comment: haha Skeet is still sleeping, allowing me to gain some points ;)

Comment: Yes, this code basically allows you to add Types at runtime and have them persisted in a SQL database, the model checked for database recreation, etc... Dynamic EF ModelBuilder yep!

Comment: Very interresting, i've been looking at a something similar for a trusted plugin environment and where they can store their data.... Are you planning on making this an opensource project?

Comment: This is part of a much bigger project I'm developing and I haven't really separated this code from my actual EF data layer implementation but I suppose I could? Actually, I'd like to believe that the EF team will eventually add more support to their API for runtime model-building and configuring :S

Comment: I'm on Twitter if you'd like to talk @maxbeaudoin I believe :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4376/discussion-between-polity-and-maxbeaudoin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last call to Invoke, you specified the wrong instance parameter. Should be 'config' rather than '_builder'

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I have no excuses...

**How-to Entity Framework & Reflection:**

```
var config = _builder.GetType()
    .GetMethod("Entity")
    .MakeGenericMethod(contentType.Type)
    .Invoke(_builder, null);

var hasKey = config.GetType().GetMethod("HasKey");

var expressionKey = typeof(Expression<>)
    .MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>)
    .MakeGenericType(contentType.Type, typeof(Guid)));

var paramEx = Expression.Parameter(contentType.Type, "t");
var lambdaEx = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(paramEx, "Id"), paramEx);

hasKey.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Guid))
    .Invoke(config, new[] { lambdaEx });
```